# How to generate the source codes from an .fba file

Tags: javascript, fitbit, fba

This question might sound crazy, but the truth is I recently developed an app for Fitbit watches and uploaded the fba file on Fitbit gallery. Then, my laptop was stolen, and because I didn't make a backup of the app, now I only have the final product without having the source codes which are .js files. I wonder if there is a way of converting that fba to the source code or any approach for recovering the source codes.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: From what I heard, .fba is just a zip file. Try unzipping maybe? `unzip app.fba`

Comment: Thanks for your comment! yes, I can unzip that file but it is not easy to convert it back to what (the structure) it was before especially if you have a complex file. The process must be done manually and is time-consuming.